# Process Automation for tasks created through Email-to-Salesforce feature

Tags: process-builder, visual-workflow, emailtosalesforce

In my org automated emails from a vendor are sent to us via the Email-to-Salesforce feature (which creates Tasks and puts the email contents into the Task) for which I would like to attach some process automation. The emails all use the `ref: <Salesforce record id>` syntax and are automatically assigned to the correct record. Using Process Builder or Flow (when a Task is Created or Updated) where the subject contains certain words, I want to update some field values on it. Tried the same with Lightning Flow that is auto-launched by Tasks being created or updated.

What I've discovered is that when the Tasks are created by Salesforce automatically, neither my Process or Flow are triggered. However, if I then go and change any of the values on the Tasks both the Process and Flow trigger (I monitor this by having them both append text to the Description field). Is this common-knowledge that I'm just unaware of, or is there a special hack I can do for when these Tasks are created?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that [this is expected behavior](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000315966&type=1&mode=1). Salesforce wants you to create an Apex trigger to handle this special case...

There is also a [feature request](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Jx7RAAS) anyone can upvote if so interested.